# How to iterate rows of dataframe in Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded format into API POST request?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, api-design

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
email        p[1]:
a@a.com       1
b@b.com       2
```

the `p[1]` field is the list ID.

How do I pass rows of this dataframe one at a time into the a API post request in the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format?

Without a dataframe when I try this code it works:

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

params = {
    'email': 'peach@peach.com',
   ' p[1]': '1',
}

url = 'https://URL/admin/api.php?api_action=contact_add&api_output=json&api_key=123ABC' 
resp = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
```

How do I pass each row of the dataframe and how do I convert the dataframe format into the `params` equalivent format?

This api does not take bulk uploads. More information can be found here about the API. https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_add

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this one at a time, you want `DataFrame.iterrows`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com'], 'p[1]': [1,2]})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    params = {'email': row.email, 'p[1]': row['p[1]']}
    print(params)

{'email': 'a@a.com', 'p[1]': 1}
{'email': 'b@b.com', 'p[1]': 2}
```

You can then pass the `params` to whatever you want one at a time inside of the loop.

Comment: @RustyShackleford This answer is on the right track, but you can speed it up a bit by leaving the dict conversion to pandas: `for params in df.to_dict(orient='records'): ... `